ASP.NET Core 8.0 - a potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client
We have an ASP.NET Core 8.0 project, where a Http request failed with this error:

A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client (filter="...dim1 eq '<tttt...").";error_category="internal_error"][X-Powered-By,ASP.NET].

I found the previous solution for ASP.NET on .NET 4.0 to use  RequestValidationMode ="2.0". But this property is only applied to .NET Framework projects - has anyone found a solution for this in .NET 8.0 ?

Where you host this application? Inside the IIS or else? Inside the .net core it will not throw this error if you don't customize the codes. Besides, the error message is x-powered-by ASP.NET, do you have asp.net host at same website?

looks like that's thrown because "<" is in a value.  Those should be htmlencoded to help prevent injection attacks.

@BrandoZhang this is a stand-alone executable project, I don't know server side details for the http request sent from the exe. The weirs  thing is some of the request can success, but some fail for the same code to create the request, and parameter as the same pattern, including "<>". I also use the urlencode when construct the request.have no idea about what should be updated to make all request succeed now.

The short answer is encode the querystring before sending to the backend server, but if the server will decode then checking, you could just use some other special character to achieve what you want.
